# Facebook iOS: requestNewPublishPermissions not asking user for new authority

Tags: ios, facebook

I am having a problem with requestNewPublishPermissions (I'm using SDK version 3.17). The Facebook docs say to log in with just read permission, and then later ask for write permission, so that's what I'm trying to do. I can get the user to log in just fine with code like this:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
{
     // Handler for session state changes
     // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
     // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
}];
```

Then when I want to post to the timeline, I ask to expand the permissions using the code below. The app kicks out to Safari with a Facebook web page. But instead of asking for write permission, that web page just says that the app was already given permission. And then when I hit okay, and control returns to the app, I do NOT have publish permission. See "this is where it ends up!" below.

I have tried going to facebook.com and deleting the permissions already given under "Apps". That didn't make any difference. I've also tried doing a publish anyway, but that gives me an error that says I don't have the correct permissions.

Any ideas?

```
- (void) requestPublishPermission:(void (^)(void)) action
{
    // Request publish_actions
    [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                          defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             if ( [FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound )
             {
                 // this is where it ends up!
             }
             else
             {
                 // Permission granted, publish the story
                 action();
             }
         }
         else
         {
             // permission denied, alert user
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: I have same problem now X(
Did you find out solution ??

Comment: No I never did. IIRC, I used the native Facebook sharing GUI as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the user you are logging in as as a Developer/Tester. Or you need to submit your app to Facebook for review.

Comment: It is true but partial scenario. If the "publish_actions" is not approved yet or the FB app only developers of the specific FB App will get the FB approval screen. It can happen in cases the user is using FB web client. Session will closed, recall open the session but new permissions are not added to the session.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and it is happening only when the user is not using the FB App and everything is happening via the Web. This is what I did to resolve the problem:

```
typedef void(^facebookPostCompBlock)(FBSession *session, NSError* err, BOOL publishActionPermissions);

- (void) obtainPostPermissionsWithComplition:(facebookPostCompBlock) comp {
    if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) {

        if ([[[FBSession activeSession] permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
            [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                                  defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)

             {
                 BOOL gotPublishActionPermissions = TRUE;
                 if ([[[FBSession activeSession] permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
                     gotPublishActionPermissions = FALSE;                     
                 }
                 if (comp) {
                     comp(session,error,gotPublishActionPermissions);
                 }
             }];
        } else {
            if (comp) {
                comp([FBSession activeSession],nil,TRUE);
            }
        }
    } else {
        BOOL openedSynchronously = [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                           defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                              allowLoginUI:YES
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
        {
            if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                [self obtainPostPermissionsWithComplition:comp];
            } else {
                BOOL gotPublishActionPermissions = TRUE;
                if ([[session permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
                    gotPublishActionPermissions = FALSE;
                    BLog(@"+ NOT FOUND +");
                } else {
                   if (comp) {
                       comp(session,error,gotPublishActionPermissions);
                   }
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

The only concern in the following (need a fail safe) is the that the session will switch from open to close over an over and you'll end up with a loop.